# How to remove timezone in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I get time and format

```
{{transaction.submitTime | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}
```

It returns

```
2015-04-23 02:18:43 +0700
```

But I want to show without `+0700`, that hour will plus 7.
How can I do that?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean in that last sentence?

Comment: So do you want it to display `'2015-04-22 19:18.43'` (i.e. UTC without the time zone) or `'2015-04-23 02:18:43'` (i.e. system time without the time zone)?

Comment: as your question. I want to get '2015-04-23 09:18:43'

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
d = new Date();
d.toLocaleString();       // -> "2/1/2013 7:37:08 AM"
d.toLocaleDateString();   // -> "2/1/2013"
d.toLocaleTimeString();  // -> "7:38:05 AM"
```

Comment: The *toLocale\** methods are entirely implementation dependant, there is no guarantee of any of those formats appearing in a random browser.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the format string you supplied in relation to the output you got:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z
2015-04-23 02:18:43 +0700
```

Note how each element of the format string corresponds to an element of the output?

`Z` represents the time zone. To get rid of it, just change the format string:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

You'll then get a time string like this:

```
2015-04-22 09:48:36
```

Comment: Thanks. But Hour still not plus 7

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [toLocaleString](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCMQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FNumber%2FtoLocaleString&ei=mHw4VaqxCoLGuATCl4GoBQ&usg=AFQjCNFMN161wjDI-F9LcvXZtxJBvx3dQg&sig2=g-eu0obZXNxkykIE2RhX3g&bvm=bv.91427555,d.c2E&cad=rja) method.

```
var date = new Date()
alert(date.toLocaleString())
```